# In Android Studio C++ code navigation and analysis doesn't work with CMake 3.7 or higher

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have *CMake* *3.12.1* installed on my system *PATH* via brew. 
I create an android project with C++ support from default Android Studio template.

Then specify CMake version in gradle.build file:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.12.1"
        }
}
```

After that, all code navigation and refactoring features in C++ code are completely broken. 
If I don't change CMake version (use CMake 3.6 from ndk-bundle) everything works fine.

Some information about my system:

```
Build: 3.2, AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, 201809171917, 

AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246, JRE 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Mac OS X(x86_64) v10.13.6 unknown, screens 1680x1050; Retina

Android Gradle Plugin: 3.2.0
Gradle: 4.6
NDK: from local.properties: 18.0.5002713; latest from SDK: 18.0.5002713; 
LLDB: LLDB 3.1 (revision: 3.1.4508709)
CMake: from local.properties: (not specified); latest from SDK: 3.6.0-rc2; from PATH: 3.12.1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/112611156